# Python Web Clawer: How to make the clawer work better

Tags: python, web-crawler

I am new to Python and recently is trying to write a web clawer to collect data from a website for my project. The amount of the data is quite large so it would take long time to collect. During which, I have met some problems:

1. 502 bad gate way - what can I do with that?
2. I use `try... expect...` to handle the exceptions but it seems still the program will be interrupted by the exception, how can I handle all the exceptions without interrupting the program?

Really thanks for help!!!

Following are my code: (Python 2.7,BeautifulSoup4.3.2,XlsxWriter0.8.7)

```
# coding: utf-8
import urllib2
import urllib
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urlparse
import xlsxwriter
import traceback;

def open_with_retries(url):
attempts = 5
for attempt in range(attempts):
    try:
        return opener.open(url)
    except:
        if attempt == attempts - 1:
            raise

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Artist_Art_B.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

ro = 0
co = 0

opener = urllib2.build_opener()
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.6) Gecko/20091201 Firefox/3.5.6' )]

# First web
response = open_with_retries(unicode("http://amma.artron.net/artronindex_artist.php"))
content = response.read()
pattern = re.compile(u'<li><a href="artronindex_pic.php(.*?) title="(.*?)".*?</a></li>',re.S)
items = re.findall(pattern,content)
for item in items:
    # Second
    try:
        res2 = open_with_retries(str("http://amma.artron.net/artronindex_pic.php?artist="+item[1]))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res2.read())
        tables = soup.find_all('tbody')
        if len(tables)>0:
            table = tables[0]
            rows = table.findChildren('tr')
            print item[1]
            for row in rows:
                links = row.find_all('a',href=True)
                for link in links:
                    url =  link['href']
                    parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
                    sort = urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)['sort'][0]
                    labe = urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)['labe'][0]
                    f = {'sort':sort,'labe':labe}
                    later = urllib.urlencode(f)

                    # Third
                    res3 = open_with_retries(str("http://amma.artron.net/artronindex_auctionseason.php?name="+item[1]+"&"+later))
                    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(res3.read())   
                    ttables = soup2.findChildren('tbody')
                    if len(tables)>0:
                        ttable = ttables[0]
                        rrows = ttable.findChildren('tr')
                        for rrow in rrows:
                            ccells = rrow.findChildren('td')
                            for ccell in ccells:
                                vvalue = unicode(ccell.string)
                                worksheet.write(ro,co,vvalue)
                                co=co+1
                                print vvalue
                        ro = ro+1
                        co = 0
    except Exception:
         traceback.print_exc()
workbook.close()
```

Comment: Your question is too generic to be answered... to get a good answer, you'll have to include the specific code that breaks.

Comment: @miraculixx Hi, I have added the code, thanks for the reminding

Comment: This code doesn't run. Try using [this tool](https://github.com/alexmojaki/askso) to help you write a better question.

Comment: @AlexHall Is there a demo of AskSO?

Comment: @DisplayName for that I'd have to host a server that runs arbitrary Python code sent by users or use a browser implementation of Python. Right now I'm not motivated to do either myself. The project is brand new.

Comment: What Python versions does it support?

Comment: @AlexHall Hi, thanks for your attention. I implemented Python2.7 and I have reformatted the code (sorry about that). And as you advised, I have downloaded the AskSO and tried to run my code on that( if you are using that to test my code, delete the first line "# coding = utf-8" and it will be able to run). But as I mentioned before that the code will take a long time to run to collect all the data, it seems it also take a long time running on the AskSo ...

Comment: @DisplayName [this file](https://github.com/alexmojaki/askso/blob/master/tox.ini) configures the versions of Python that tests run on. Also I wasn't notified of your question, mention me.

Comment: @IvyLin it will be difficult to help without knowing where the error is happening. Instead of `print "Error"` which hides the problem, use `import traceback; traceback.print_exc()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) I'm guessing that the 502 is a temporary error that can be resolved by retrying the request. Replace calls to `opener.open` with calls to this function:

```
def open_with_retries(url):
    attempts = 5
    for attempt in range(attempts):
        try:
            return opener.open(url)
        except:
            if attempt == attempts - 1:
                raise
```

(2) You are already ensuring that the program doesn't stop completely with this code:

```
for item in items:
    try:
        ...
    except ValueError:
        ...
```

Although this will only work if the exception being thrown has the type `ValueError`. The loop will go on to the next `item` and keep running. You can follow the same pattern with `for link in links` to make sure that as many `link`s as possible within an `item` are processed.

Comment: Thankyou so much! I have changed the code and also change the "ValueError" to "Exception". Now i am running to see if it will works fine, hope it will work out :)